# Python Selenium scraping incorrect set of brackets (Python, Selenium, MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, selenium

## Question:

I have some code which scrapes https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/# it gets the text inside each set of brackets and adds them to MySQL database by natching name, this works correctly however if the entry has 2 sets of brackets it selects the second see below.

## Example

[image: Incorrect set of brackets chosen]

## Code:

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="user",
  passwd="passwd",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

d = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Uskompuf/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page=1')
def cpus(_source):
  result = soup(_source, 'html.parser').find('ul', {'id':'category_content'}).find_all('li')
  _titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
  data = [list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result]
  return _titles, [a for *_, [a] in filter(None, data)]


_titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
print(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
mydb.commit()
_last_page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('#page\=\d+')})[-1].text
for i in range(2, int(_last_page)+1):
   d.get(f'https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page={i}') 
   time.sleep(3)
   _titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
   sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
   mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
   mydb.commit()

mydb.commit()
```

## Update

I tired the following code from @Daniel Scott

Changing

```
_titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
```

To

```
_titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else str(x.text).split(")")[0])(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
```

However i still seem to get `on-die` and `on die` any ideas?

## Update 2

Here are the class both brackets seem to be part of `title` however

[image]

I was thinking i might have to change this `str(x.text).split(")`?

## Update 3

I have changed the code to

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="root",
  passwd="passwd",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

d = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Uskompuf/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page=1')
def cpus(_source):
  result = soup(_source, 'html.parser').find('ul', {'id':'category_content'}).find_all('li')
  _titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
  data = [list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result]
  data2=[]
  for i in data:
      ii=0
      arr2=[]
      for c in i:
        # Skep the rest of section if we've already seen a closing bracket
        if (")" in c) and ii>1:
            a=1
        if ")" in c:
            ii+=1
        try:
            arr2.append(c.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
        except Exception:
            pass
      data2.append(arr2)
  data = data2
  return _titles, [a for *_, [a] in filter(None, data)]

_titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
mydb.commit()
_last_page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('#page\=\d+')})[-1].text
for i in range(2, int(_last_page)+1):
   d.get(f'https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page={i}') 
   time.sleep(3)
   _titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
   sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
   mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
   mydb.commit()

mydb.commit()
```

As per answer update however this no doesn't work at all with all family values remaining Null in my database.

After the data operation `print(data)` returns .

Any ideas?

## Update 4

No luck back to base 1.

## Update 5

If I `print([list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result])`

This is an example of what I don't want, i need to get rid of on-die.

```
[['0'], ['0'], ['OEM/Tray'], ['Godavari'], ['on-die']]
```

## Update 6

I think this is the code that needs to be changed:

```
return _titles, [a for *_, [a] in filter(None, data)]
```

## Other:

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you mean i think i figured out the problem please see update 5 & 6

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change the line:

```
_titles = list(filter(None,
[(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div',
{'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
```

To this:

```
_titles = list(filter(None,
[(lambda x:'' if x is None else str(x.text).split(")")[0])(i.find('div',
{'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
```

That should change it so that it separates double brackets into the two strings, and only takes the 1st one. Let me know if that works for you!

Reference: [Splitting strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

## Update

My scraper is being really intermittent at the moment, and I can't properly troubleshoot this.

Following this line:

```
data = [list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result]
```

Paste this:

```
data2=[]
    for i in data:
        ii=0
        arr2=[]
        for c in i:
            # Skep the rest of section if we've already seen a closing bracket
            if (")" in c) and ii>1:
                a=1
            if ")" in c:
                ii+=1
            try:
                arr2.append(c.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
            except Exception:
                pass
        data2.append(arr2)
    data = data2
```

It's code that is so ugly, it cries out for downvotes. But at least it's something as a start for you so you aren't slowed down. It goes through the array and disregards the second bracketed occurrence in every ul.

Cheers mate.

Comment: Trying it now!!

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work please see my update above! Thanks

Comment: Could you post the stack trace you are getting? I am not familiar with 'on-die'.

Comment: Ohh sorry, on-die is the text inside the second set of brackets. As seen in the following image https://imgur.com/a/LaD4mfj i am trying to get the text inside the first if 2 sets exist

Comment: @Uskompuf Ah, thanks! I get it now -  haha. I am a bit suspicious that the first title is sitting in a tag other than <'title'>. Could you paste the tags from the inspector window into your question so we can look through them? I just want to see that second list-item. I do lots of web scraping and have run into things like this often. Stuff like this is usually from unique tags or hidden escape characters.

Comment: which leads me to believe maybe need to change this? str(x.text).split(")

Comment: @Uskompuf Ya, you can change that one back. I updated this answer. Take a peek - its not perfect though.

Comment: getting an unexpected indent under data2=[]

Comment: if i print data after your code i get [[], [], [], [], [],

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186214/discussion-between-daniel-scott-and-uskompuf).